# C++ erase() in a function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, erase

It is expected that element '2' has been removed when the set elements are output in the 'helper' function. But the actual result is still '1 2 3 4 5'.
However, the size of the set is 4.
I wonder the underlying problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

void helper(set<int> myset, set<int>::iterator it) {
    myset.erase(it);

    cout << "size:" << myset.size() << endl;
    for(auto el : myset)
        cout << el << " ";
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    set<int> myset = {1,2,3,4,5};

    auto it = myset.begin();
    it++;
    helper(myset,it);
}
```

Comment: `void helper(set<int> myset` passes a copy of the set. The iterator is not associated with the copy, only the original.

Answer (score 3):

`it` in `helper` is an an iterator to the `myset`in `main`. But the `myset` in `helper`is a *copy* of the `myset` in `main`. That means that the `it` in the `helper` function does not refer to an element in the `myset` that you are using in that function so it's undefined behavior. You would need to make `myset` in `helper` a reference. Try :

```
void helper(set<int> & myset, set<int>::iterator it)
```

Edit : This also solves another problem you may not have noticed. Previously, when taking `myset` by value, you were merely modifying the local copy. You would (try to) erase an element from the copy and then print it but this would not affect the original `myset` which was passed to the function in `main`. By making it a reference, changes to `myset` in the `helper` function will actually be changing the original `myset`.

Comment: Using the same name for your arguments as you used for your objects at the call site make it needlessly complicated to explain the problem. Consider avoiding reusing names when asking questions in the future.

Comment: You should also mention that passing by value has another problem - changing copy will not affect original set, even if OP would pass key instead of iterator

Comment: Thank you for your advice.But why the value of myset.size() is 4 as expected?

Comment: @XINLIU You problem was causing *undefinded behavior*. At that point, nothing is guaranteed to make sense. In your case, your set reported a size of 4 while iterating over it identified 5 elements. Normally, a container can never do that, but by entering undefined behavior you forfeit the right to reason about what your code will do.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your `set` by value to your helper function. So your iterator refers to the original set, not the copy made in the function.

Even *if* the iterator was still valid for the copy, changing the copy is not what you want. You want to change the original.

Pass the set by reference to your helper to make it do what you want.